# How to Add Requests in Google Sheets

Tags: c#, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

When adding or getting a cell, the requestBody is quite simple, but when dealing with Batch Updates, it seems to be a lot more complicated.

```
        List<Data.Request> requests = new List<Data.Request>();  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

        Data.BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest requestBody = new Data.BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
        requestBody.Requests = requests;

        SpreadsheetsResource.BatchUpdateRequest request = service.Spreadsheets.BatchUpdate(requestBody, spreadsheetId);

        Data.BatchUpdateSpreadsheetResponse response = request.Execute();
```

Using [Google's Batch Update Examples](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate), I have a base for the code, but I do not know how to add the requests that are necessary for what I need. Using the API Explorer, I have the correct requestBody:

> {"requests": [ { "sortRange": { "range": { "sheetId": 0, "startRowIndex": 1 }, "sortSpecs": [ { "sortOrder": "ASCENDING", "dimensionIndex": 0 } ] } } ] }

so I tried to do something like this:

```
requests.Add(new Request().SortRange.Range.SheetId = 0);
```

but it does not work that way.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code instead,

```
/*
 * BEFORE RUNNING:
 * ---------------
 * 1. If not already done, enable the Google Sheets API
 *    and check the quota for your project at
 *    https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/sheets
 * 2. Install the Java client library on Maven or Gradle. Check installation
 *    instructions at https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client.
 *    On other build systems, you can add the jar files to your project from
 *    https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/download/sheets/v4/java
 */

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.BatchUpdateSpreadsheetResponse;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.Request;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SheetsExample {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    // The spreadsheet to apply the updates to.
    String spreadsheetId = "my-spreadsheet-id"; // TODO: Update placeholder value.

    // A list of updates to apply to the spreadsheet.
    // Requests will be applied in the order they are specified.
    // If any request is not valid, no requests will be applied.
    List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<>(); // TODO: Update placeholder value.

    // TODO: Assign values to desired fields of `requestBody`:
    BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest requestBody = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
    requestBody.setRequests(requests);

    Sheets sheetsService = createSheetsService();
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.BatchUpdate request =
        sheetsService.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId, requestBody);

    BatchUpdateSpreadsheetResponse response = request.execute();

    // TODO: Change code below to process the `response` object:
    System.out.println(response);
  }

  public static Sheets createSheetsService() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    // TODO: Change placeholder below to generate authentication credentials. See
    // https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/java#step_3_set_up_the_sample
    //
    // Authorize using one of the following scopes:
    //   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
    //   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"
    //   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
    GoogleCredential credential = null;

    return new Sheets.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
        .setApplicationName("Google-SheetsSample/0.1")
        .build();
  }
}
```

I got it from [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate).
Maybe this site could help as well to understand the parameters.

You may also check this related post: [Google Sheets SortSpecs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45340136/google-sheets-sortspecs)