# Google Sheets SortSpecs

Tags: c#, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to create a request for Google Sheets, but I'm having problems with the sortSpecs method.

```
var test = new Request()
        {
            SortRange = new SortRangeRequest()
            {
                Range = new GridRange()
                {
                    SheetId = 0,
                    StartRowIndex = 1                        
                },
                SortSpecs = new SortSpec()
                {
                    SortOrder = "ASCENDING",
                    DimensionIndex = 0
                }
            }
        };
```

When using this, everything works correctly except for the SortSpec. Visual Studio gives the error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data.SortSpec'
>   to
>   System.Collections.Generic.IList'
>   An explicit conversion exists

**UPDATE:**

There are no more build errors, but now I have another error when executing the code.

```
        List<Data.Request> requests = new List<Data.Request>();  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

        Data.SortSpec so = new Data.SortSpec();
        so.SortOrder = "ASCENDING";

        Data.SortSpec di = new Data.SortSpec();
        di.DimensionIndex = 0;

        List<Data.SortSpec> ss = new List<Data.SortSpec>();
        ss.Add(so);
        ss.Add(di);

        var test = new Request()
        {
            SortRange = new SortRangeRequest()
            {
                Range = new GridRange()
                {
                    SheetId = 0,
                    StartRowIndex = 1
                },
                SortSpecs = ss
            }

        };

        requests.Add(test);
```

The exception given is

> Message[Invalid requests[0].sortRange: No sort order specified.] Location[ - ] Reason[badRequest] Domain[global]

Answer (score 0):

Per the [reference docs](https://devsite.googleplex.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#SortRangeRequest), `SortSpecs` is a list of items, not a single item.  The error message is also saying that (it can't convert SortSpec to an IList).  If you want to use a single SortSpec for your sorting specifications, create a list, put that single item in it, and assign `SortSpecs` to that list.

Comment: So I tried doing this:

Data.SortSpec so = new Data.SortSpec();
            so.SortOrder = "ASCENDING";

            Data.SortSpec di = new Data.SortSpec();
            di.DimensionIndex = 0;

            List<Data.SortSpec> ss = new List<Data.SortSpec>();
            ss.Add(so);
            ss.Add(di);

With "SortSpecs = ss" under sortRange in the request. There are no build errors, but when it runs, I get the error "Invalid requests[0].sortRange: No sort order specified. [400]"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are instantiating 2 new SortSpec objects but you just need 1 object instantiation and assign values to 2 of it's fields "SortOrder" and "DimentionIndex". I had same sheet sorting requirement and I was able to solve it this way:

```
        BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest reqbody = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
        SortSpec ss = new SortSpec();
        ss.DimensionIndex = 1;
        ss.SortOrder = "ASCENDING";

        GridRange rangetosort = new GridRange();
        rangetosort.StartColumnIndex = 0;
        rangetosort.EndColumnIndex = 12;
        rangetosort.StartRowIndex = 2;
        rangetosort.EndRowIndex = totalrows;
        rangetosort.SheetId = sheetgid;

        SortRangeRequest srr = new SortRangeRequest();
        srr.Range = rangetosort;
        IList<SortSpec> sortspecs = new List<SortSpec>();
        sortspecs.Add(ss);
        srr.SortSpecs = sortspecs;
        Request req1 = new Request();
        req1.SortRange = srr;
        IList<Request> req2 = new List<Request>();
        req2.Add(req1);
        reqbody.Requests = req2;

        SpreadsheetsResource.BatchUpdateRequest sortreq = sheetsrv1.Spreadsheets.BatchUpdate(reqbody, spid);
        try
        {
            sortreq.Execute();
            Console.WriteLine("Sorting Operation successfull");
        }
        catch(Exception ex6)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex6.Message);
        }
```